# Java jSoup Elements Replace Missing Element

Tags: java, replace, jsoup, element

I'm crawling a website using jSoup to obtain information from the adverts it displays. Most the adverts contain common elements but for some they are missing. I'm trying to crawl for all of the adverts, whilst including those that don't share the common elements, but I'm struggling. Here's the basics of what I've got:

```
    Elements gene = doc.select("div.item");

    for (Element c : gene) {

                    Elements monk1 = c.select("li.cool");
                    Elements monk2 = c.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("src", "/images/notthere.gif");

                    if (monk1.isEmpty()) {
                       monk1 = monk2;
                    }
                    String[] price = {monk1.text()};
                    model1.setValueAt(price[0], xf, 2);
                    xf++;
                    xf++;

                }
```

It looks for elements within the elements "gene" in the HTML. "li.cool" is present in most of the "gene" elements, but for some its missing. For each time "li.cool" is missing, I want to replace the null element with a simple string. How do I do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can add text using `text()` method.

```
if(monk1 == null)
monk1.text("string")
```

You can view the explanation [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-text).

Comment: Aka ash thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work! I'm now trying to add an new element created prior to the for loop every time I get a null element, which also isn't working.